# Launch screens may not set custom classnames

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I tried to add a custom class to my Table View Cell, but after I added it it gives the following error:

[image]

I often read that I can't use custom classes in the LaunchScreen but I haven't touched this file. Can anyone help me?

[image]

This are my general settings for the main and the launch interface.

I am using Swift.

Comment: Try Clean Build Cmd+Option+K. May be you added any custom class for launch screen before and removed it after some time.

Comment: @Yash : nope that would NOT work. You are not allowed to use custom class in Launch Screen file. Rather then treating this file as VC, think of it as a static image.

Comment: @Bishal Ghimire I know we are not allowed thats the screenshot is also showing in the post but it is also a xib file so maybe custom class added by mistake by the user.

Comment: @Yash how Can i check that ?

Comment: @Yash And if i click on the error it opens always the Main.storyboard?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Go to the properties of your `Main.storyboard` and check that `Use as Launch Screen` isn't selected.  It sounds like you have selected it by mistake.

[image]

Comment: Omg thanks man,  now it works fine. I can't vote up for your post because I have not enough points, but feel voted. 

Answer (score 16):

## iOS 13 note:

Prior to iOS 13, you had both:

- `Main.storyboard`
- `LaunchScreen.storyboard`

Starting from iOS 13 by default you have SwiftUI. As a result you no longer have the `Main.storyboard`. You only have `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.

As for their differences see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891481/what-is-the-difference-between-launchscreen-storyboard-and-main-storyboard)

And perhaps like me, you just saw the word storyboard and jumped right at it and later realized you're not building against **Main**.storyboard.

The fix is simple and is mentioned in [Paulw11 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37769167/5175709)

### Why that has happened?

It's because SwiftUI has somewhat deprecated the need of storyboards and tends to put focus on using previews as a [single source of truth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398373/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-source-of-truth-ssot-in-the-context-of-swiftui).

---

If you still want to work with the storyboard then what you have to do is upon creating the project set the 'User Interface' to 'Storyboard':

[image]

Comment: lol. This is my 2nd answer to this question. I supposed I realized that when writing my 2nd answer. But re-realizing that after 3yrs is interesting.

Answer (score 7):

I always have a separate splash screen which is the first view controller  app loads.
[image: Splash Screen Storyboard]

This is the file where you want to add all the business logical or display spinner / loader etc.

For this to work you have to setup Deployment target of your project as shown.
[image: Target Deployment info]

Note that you can not add any other custom class to `LaunchScreen`. It is an ViewController to just show while app is about to start. In this phase of app life cycle nothing has yet been started. Its almost similar to static image ( It used to be only static image till iOS7 ). Starting for iOS9 or XCode 7 only it was changed to storyboard previously it used to be XIB file. Hence you can not add custom class objects to `LaunchScreen` as this is a phase where app is still to be loaded or started.

Comment: It looks exactly like your example. I don't has added stuff into the LaunchSreen file. Instead of Splash.storyboard i am using Main.storyboard.

Comment: @GuteLaune: yes you can use Main.Storyboard to add your custom class objects. Like I said LaunchScreen File is like Static Image. While its loaded no code are executed yet. Hence no point of adding custom class objects. Treat it like an image with added feature of auto-layout.

Comment: I don't have added code in launch screen file. I added a photo in post above and if u see I do it like you said, but I still have the error.

Answer (score 7):

I made the same mistake.

## WRONG:

[image]

---

Very likely what you **intended** to do was such:

## CORRECT:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To add on to Yash's comment, this error is misleading. If the Custom Class field is empty for your ViewController then you should also check every object on your view and see if their custom classes are empty as well, you can't even have a custom label set for the Launch Page.

This is what got me and took me a while to figure out, had a custom class set on one of my labels by accident from a cut + paste.

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons for this error.

I got this error because launchscreen.storyboard and main.storyboard had same custom class as "viewController.swift".

Try removing the custom class from launchscreen.storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your -> launchScreen.storyboard then got to your -> identity and types -> uncheck the box -> use as launch Screen. Changing it in General -> App Icons and Launch images -> Launch Screen File drop down -> LaunchScreen instead of launchScreen.storyboard won't help(stop) do the above. make sure all your constraints are set properly easier way just copy the constraint settings from your main story board.